# How to change color of Text without losing formatting

Tags: text, colors, formatting, extendscript, after-effects

I can change the text color, but the formatting is changing either! Half of my text is in Bold, and other half is in Italic. But in the end all text change to Bold.

```
var proj = app.project;
var theComposition = app.project.activeItem;
var theTextLayer = theComposition.layers[1];

var textProp1 = theTextLayer.property("Text").property("Source Text");
var textProp2 = theTextLayer.property("Source Text").value;
textProp2.fillColor = [1,1,1];  
textProp1.setValue(textProp2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `TextDocument`: `textProp1.setValue(textProp2);` it's set all the `TextDocument` properties.
Adobe don't support multi formats per Text Layer via Extendscript(e.x.: fillColor, fontSize, fontFamily etc.), so the layer gets the properties of the first letter which is in your case Bold.

What I can suggest you is to add a Fill effect to the layer and change the value in the effect.
Here's a code for that:

```
var fillEffect = theTextLayer.property('ADBE Effect Parade').addProperty('ADBE Fill');
fillEffect.property('Color').setValue([1,1,1]);
```

Comment: Thx Ziki. I don't like this kind of approaching but... I see I don't have other way...

Thnx! ExtendScript is so unproductive.. :(

Comment: I hate this too, but as I understand from posts in the Adobe forums they aren't going to improve it because the Extenedscript community isn't big enough to make some improvements.